# Find the limit of the sequence $\frac{2^{n-1} + 3^n} {4^n - 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I have done right here...

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{2^{n-1} + 3^n}{4^n - 1}.$$

I know that I have to eliminate the lowest exponents in each part which is $2^{n-1}$ at the numerator and $1$ at the denominator but how to eliminate it?

Comment: Divide by $4^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide numerator and denominator by $4^{n}$. Can you now see that the limit is $0$?